# Different frequency to different cores in gem5 simulation?

Tags: multicore, gem5

Is it possible to set the different frequency to the CPU cores for simulation? It means, suppose I have two core C1 and C2 can I want to set 1GhZ to C1 and 2GHz to C2. In the group, I found that using big/little core for ARM ISA it might be possible. However, in the gem5 official site, it is mentioned that gem5 does not support heterogeneous cores. I want the varying frequency for X-86 and ALPHA ISA, is it possible in SE/Full mode. Kindly advise.

Thank you

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, but I would try to have a look inside `m5out/config.ini` to see if there is a frequency parameter, and then try to modify the config to change those parameters, possibly with `fs.py --param`, but maybe custom config is needed. A quick look shows that `[system.cpu_clk_domain]` is connected to the CPU node `[system.cpu]` so I'd focus on that one first. Mailing list thread: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg16595.html